# Issue displaying JPG in Safari for Yosemite OSX

Tags: java, utf-8, safari, jpeg, osx-yosemite

I am currently have issues displaying jpgs from a java bytestream in Safari (Yosemite OS X version). The image displays fine in all other browsers including earlier versions of Safari. Does anyone know of any bugs with the newest version of Safari displaying jpgs? Has anyone else had this issue and have a fix.

```
        byte[] checkImage = checkImageString.getBytes(CommonConstants.ENCODING);

        checkImage = Base64.decodeBase64(checkImage);

        if ( null != checkImage ) {
            int imageLength = checkImage.length;
            response.setContentType(CommonConstants.JPEG_MIME_TYPE);
            response.setContentLength(imageLength);
            // to prevent caching
            response.setHeader( CommonConstants.ACCEPT_RANGES_HEADER, CommonConstants.BYTES);
            response.setHeader( CommonConstants.EXPIRES_HEADER, CommonConstants.EXPIRE );
            response.setHeader( CommonConstants.CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, CommonConstants.NO_CACHE );
            response.setHeader( CommonConstants.PRAGMA_HEADER, CommonConstants.NO_CACHE );
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
            sos.write(checkImage, 0, imageLength);
            sos.flush();
            sos.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was not a coding issue but an issue with the service that returns the image byte string. –